# JQuery not showing a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am making a back-to-top button and I cannot get the button to show.

Here is my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var btt = $('.back-to-top');
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var self = $(this),
            height = self.height(),
            top = self.scrollTop();
        if(top > height) {
            if(!btt.is(':visible')) {
                btt.show();
            }
        } else {
            btt.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to top</a>
```

Comment: What is back-to-top in your html? Is it the id or the class of the button?

Comment: @Stamen Its the class. I have added it to the question

Comment: It is possible that the link is displayed, but it is not visible, because you have scrolled to the bottom of the page. In other words, the link may not move with the scroll in the html. I suggest you add some console.log or alert debug messages to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Well do you have html or body css height as 100%. Its not able to detect scroll on Chrome in that case.

here is the solution to tackle this; 
[jQuery Scrolling issue with body height 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164421/jquery-scrolling-issue-with-body-height-100)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Add some console.log(top+":"+height); to your code right before the if/else so you can see this. But the height and scrolltop aren't what you think they are.
I think if you do some math with the height of the containing container you can do what you want.  Use the chrome/firefox dev console to see the output of console.log.

Comment: You'll probably want the scrollBottom 
var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();